# My kmeans clustering doens't seem to work well

Tags: python, k-means

I have a dataframe df that looks like this

```
user_id, user $sales, customer visits
A         1000         20
B          500         10
C        90000         50
...        ...        ...
```

My code goes here, 
Step1

```
X= preprocessing.scale(df)

wcss = []
for i in range(1,30):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1,30), wcss)
plt.title('Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
```

the above returns 4 as optimal cluster for me, 
Step2

```
kmeans = KMeans(4, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
labels = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
X['labels']=pd.Series(labels)
```

I did a summary read of the 4 user clusters and compare their total sales and customer visits using mean and medium, but there doesn't seem to be much difference among them, ie the clustering process didn't do a good job in separating users with different attributes into different cluster. Is there something wrong or missing in the process I described?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's entirely possible that the data is not well separable by kmeans clustering. Have you plotted the data points with their cluster colors or boundaries? Does there seem to be clear separation? What other clustering algorithms have you tried?

Comment: I have tried in R and it splits into 4 clusters with clear boundaries, but not with this algorithm in Python.  I don't think it's the problem with the dataframe not well separable.